# How to make variable accept strings

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make this code keep going? I tried put an x == to str, but I think that could not be the answer.

```
while True:
    x = int(input("Please enter an integer: 
"))

if x < 0:
    x = 0
    print('Negative changed to zero')
elif x == 0:
        print('Zero')
elif x == 1:
        print('Single')
else:
    x == str :
        input("please enter a string")
```

Comment: What do you mean "keep going"?

Comment: What do you want the code to _do_? Specifically, do you want to enter an integer or a string? Or both?

Comment: Simple, accept int, str and print what ever is there to print. @Veky

Comment: @chepner Keep going as an not stop until I use an escape key.

Comment: Then fix your indentation. You don't need to check the value of `x` in order to make an infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. '1' is a str, right? But int('1') is an int. So what do you want to print? I think what would be most helpful is to provide a transcript of some session: what is input, and what is written out (and how it all ends, if it does).

Comment: @veky I settled with '1', it seems like it isn't possible unless using a try: or errorException to accept the whatever entered.

Comment: You can accept whatever is entered, if you accept the fact that it will be a string. input returns a string. You can ask whether that string can be parsed as an integer, but you cannot usefully ask whether it is a string, because the answer will always be 'yes'. isinstance(input(), str) will always return True.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your loop can have one of two effects: either `x` is guaranteed to be an `int`, or you'll raise a `ValueError`. Catch the error and restart the loop, or continue with the body knowing that `x` is an `int`

```
while True:
    x_str = input("Please enter an integer: ")
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("{} is not an integer; please try again".format(x))
        continue

    if x < 0:
        x = 0
        print('Negative changed to zero')
    elif x == 0:
        print('Zero')
    elif x == 1:
        print('Single')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guess what you wanted. I think you wanted a function that is like input, but with a strange twist: if what is entered (x) can be interpreted as an integer, then it returns the integer itself, not x. For example, if the user enters -72, it returns -72, not '-72'. Of course, if the user enters something that cannot be interpreted as an integer, the function returns it without modification.

Of course, being strongly typed, Python doesn't provide such a function, but it's easy to write one. And you don't even need `try` if you just intend to accept "ordinary"-looking integers.

```
def intput(prompt=''):
    entered = input(prompt)
    if entered[entered.startswith('-'):].isdigit(): return int(entered)
    else: return entered

while True:
    x = intput('Please enter an integer: ')
    if x < 0:
       x = 0
       print('Negative input changed to zero')
    elif x == 0: print('Zero')
    elif x == 1: print('Single')
    elif isinstance(x, str): print('You have entered a string that cannot be '
        'easily interpreted as an integer.')
```